# Zurb Foundation 6 Drop dowm menu problem

Tags: theming, 8, javascript

I am creating a theme with Drupal 8, and I am having a problem with the Foundation drop down menu. I included Zurb foundation with Gulp and NPM. I think the problem is with the Foundation JavaScript because the Foundation CSS is working.

Here is my .info.yml code

```
    name: test Theme
    description: test theme
    type: theme
    core: 8.x
    libraries:
      - grt_magazine_theme/global-css
      - grt_magazine_theme/global-js 
    stylesheets-remove:
      - core/themes/stable/css/views/views.module.css
      - core/themes/stable/css/system/components/align.module.css

    regions:
      top_nav: 'Top Navigation'
      header: 'Header'
      logo: 'Logo'
      top_ad_banner: 'ad banner'
      main_nav: 'Main Navigation'
```

I created a libraries.yml file whose content is the following.

```
    global-css:
      css:
        theme:
          css/app.css: {}

    global-js: 
      js:
        bower_components/what-input/what-input.js: {}
        bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js: {}
        js/app.js: {}
      dependencies:
        - core/jquery
```

This is my page--front.html.twig file.

```
<div class="top-bar" id="main-menu">
        <ul class="menu vertical medium-horizontal expanded medium-text-center" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown">
            <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Tech</a>
                <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
                    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Energy</a>
                <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
                    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
{{ page.top_nav }}
{{ page.header }}
{{ page.logo }}
{{ page.top_ad_banner }}
```

When I log out, the drop down menu works perfectly; when I log in, this is what I get.

> [image: screenshot]